# Reduce lines of repeated code in React with Styled Components

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

building an accordion style component so that in the collapsed state, only the first 40 characters are displayed, and when expanded the user can see the entire content. I'm new to React/Styled Components but feel like I'm repeating my styles a lot when there is bound to be a more efficient way to chain on styles to existing components, can anyone advice?

```
const Accordion = styled.div`
  background-color: #e5e9eb;
  height: 87px;
  width: 612px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #27282a;
  margin-bottom: 48px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  span {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-left: 24px;
  }
`;

const AccordionExpanded = styled.div`
  background-color: #e5e9eb;
  height: 174px;
  width: 612px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #27282a;
  margin-bottom: 48px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  span {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-left: 24px;
  }
`;

const Title = styled.h3`
font-size: 12px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding-left: 24px;
`;

const ExpandIcon = styled.img`
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
float: right;
margin-right: 12px;
`;

const CollapseIcon = styled.img`
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
float: right;
margin-right: 12px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
`;

const ExpandableString = ({ attribute, className }: Props) => {
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = React.useState(false);
  const fullDescription = attribute.readonlyvalue;
  const shortHeading = fullDescription.substring(0, 40) + '...';

  function toggleContent() {
    setIsExpanded(prev => !prev);
  }

  return (
    isExpanded ? <AccordionExpanded className={className}>
      <Title>Goods being sent</Title>
      <span>{fullDescription}</span>
      <CollapseIcon onClick={toggleContent} src={chevron} alt="Collapse content" />
    </AccordionExpanded> : <Accordion className={className}>
      <Title>Goods being sent</Title>
      <span>{shortHeading}</span>
      <ExpandIcon onClick={toggleContent} src={chevron} alt="Expand content" />
    </Accordion>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this npm library to write vanilla css as classes, then generate them into variables to use for React styled components.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@inspiraller/create-css-vars

Answer (score 1):

use css from styled-components to wrap your repeated code.

syntax=>

```js
import styled,{css} from 'styled-components'

const repeatedstyle=css`
    //duplicate styles
`
const maincomponent=styled.div`
    ${repeatedstyle}
`;
```

```js
import styled,{css} from 'styled-components'

const accordianstyles=css`
    background-color: #e5e9eb;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #27282a;
    margin-bottom: 48px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
`;
const accordianspanstyles=css`
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-left: 24px;
`;
const iconstyles=css`
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 12px;
`;

const Accordion = styled.div`
  height: 87px;
  width: 612px;
  ${accordianstyles}
  span {
      ${accordianspanstyles}
  }
`;

const AccordionExpanded = styled.div`
  height: 174px;
  width: 612px;
  ${accordianstyles}

  span {
    ${accordianspanstyles}
  }
`;

const Title = styled.h3`
font-size: 12px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding-left: 24px;
`;

const ExpandIcon = styled.img`
    ${iconstyles}
`;

const CollapseIcon = styled.img`
    ${iconstyles}
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
`;

const ExpandableString = ({ attribute, className }: Props) => {
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = React.useState(false);
  const fullDescription = attribute.readonlyvalue;
  const shortHeading = fullDescription.substring(0, 40) + '...';

  function toggleContent() {
    setIsExpanded(prev => !prev);
  }

  return (
    isExpanded ? <AccordionExpanded className={className}>
      <Title>Goods being sent</Title>
      <span>{fullDescription}</span>
      <CollapseIcon onClick={toggleContent} src={chevron} alt="Collapse content" />
    </AccordionExpanded> : <Accordion className={className}>
      <Title>Goods being sent</Title>
      <span>{shortHeading}</span>
      <ExpandIcon onClick={toggleContent} src={chevron} alt="Expand content" />
    </Accordion>
  );
};
```